# S3 request signing with amazonka

Tags: haskell, amazon-s3

Does [`amazonka`](http://brendanhay.nz/amazonka-doc/) have any API to generate v4 authorization headers for [`S3 request` as documented here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html)? I couldn't find any when I looked - so, asking here. The reason I am asking is because I will like to make streaming `REST` request to `S3` using `pipes` libraries. `amazonka` seems to be using `conduit` for underlying `request` and `response` bodies. So, I am hoping to re-use the core `authorization` header generation work already done in `amazonka`, and use `pipes` libraries for streaming REST requests.